# How can i wait for OnPostExecute to finish in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to execute `AsyncTask` but when `AsyncTask` start and `doInBackground` finish (value returned), it is skipping the `OnPostExecute` and running the code `requestTask2.execute()` below, before i change the value in `OnPostExecute`, it is trying to run `if condition` so i'm getting null.

**Let me explain with the code :**

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    Intent gt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, favorite.class);
                    String password = userInput.getText().toString();
                    String kadi =  userInput2.getText().toString();
RequestTask2 requestTask2 = new RequestTask2();
requestTask2.execute("http://www.example.com/androfav/?fav2="+kadi+":"+password).get();


 if (asd2[0][0]!=null && asd2[1][0]!=null ) {
 // This if condition works before on Post Excecute and it is causing the problem.


if (asd2[0][0].equals(password) && asd2[1][0].endsWith(kadi) ) { 
 // Codes
 }}

 class RequestTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Diziler Yükleniyor \n Lütfen Bekleyin...");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri2) {
        HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response2;
        String responseString2 = null;
        try {
            response2 = httpclient2.execute(new HttpGet(uri2[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine2 = response2.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine2.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response2.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString2 = out.toString();
            } else {
                // Closes the connection.
                response2.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine2.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString2;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {
        super.onPostExecute(result2);
        try {

            JSONArray jsonResponse2 = new JSONArray(result2);
            asd2 = new String[3][jsonResponse2.length()];
     //............................... Codes
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

How can i wait for `OnPostExecute` before the `if` condition works.
Hope i could understand myself.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask as the name suggests is Asynchronous. You need to move the if condition to `onPostExecute`.

Move the below to `onPostExecute`

```
JSONArray jsonResponse2 = new JSONArray(result2);
asd2 = new String[3][jsonResponse2.length()];
if (asd2[0][0]!=null && asd2[1][0]!=null ) {


if (asd2[0][0].equals(password) && asd2[1][0].endsWith(kadi) ) { 
// Codes
}
}
```

Edit:

I din't notice you called `get()`. Calling `get()` makes Asynctask no more asynchronous. You should never call `get()` just `execute()` is enough.

Why do you need to call `get()` which blocks the ui thread waiting for the task to be finished.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I dont know how i didn't see this. It works quite well thank you.

Comment: @user3583237 you are welcome http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get(). I think you misunderstood the use of asynctask that led to this mistake

Comment: Yes i did misunderstand the AsynTask proccess, but now i understood. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You should always avoid calling `get()` when using `AsyncTask`.  Instead, do all of your post-processing in `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {
    super.onPostExecute(result2);
    try {
        JSONArray jsonResponse2 = new JSONArray(result2);
        asd2 = new String[3][jsonResponse2.length()];
        if (asd2[0][0]!=null && asd2[1][0]!=null ) {
            if (asd2[0][0].equals(password) && asd2[1][0].endsWith(kadi) ) { 
                // Codes
            }
        }
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are completely right, i was trying to wait for the AsyncTask, i thought maybe it works, but didnt. 
Thanks, you got a very good point. Not need to use `get()`.