# How to wait until onPostExecute finishes

Tags: android, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, android-asynctask

So I am new to programming, what I'm trying to do is to make an android app that will give to the client the nearest and fastest way to go the cinema/gas station/market. The problem with that is that first I need to find the nearest places via google api get the lats and lngs and then use them to direction api.
So what I have done is this:

***GetNearbyPlaces.java***

```
public class GetNearbyPlaces extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>
{
private String googleplaceData, url;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... objects)
{
    mMap = (GoogleMap) objects[0];
    url = (String) objects[1];

    DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
    try
    {
        googleplaceData = downloadUrl.ReadTheURL(url);
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return googleplaceData;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{

    List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
    DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
    nearbyPlacesList = dataParser.parse(s);
    DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Log.d("Message","telos execute ");

}

private void DisplayNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList)
{
    for (int i=0; i<nearbyPlacesList.size(); 
       {
        Log.d("Message","mesa stin for ");
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> googleNearbyPlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
        String nameOfPlace = googleNearbyPlace.get("place_name");
        String vicinity = googleNearbyPlace.get("vicinity");

        double lat = Double.parseDouble(googleNearbyPlace.get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(googleNearbyPlace.get("lng"));

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(nameOfPlace + " : " + vicinity);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
    }

}
```

}

***GoogleUserMaps.java***

```
case R.id.gasstation_nearby:
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(userLocMarkerOptions);
            mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

            url = getUrl(latitude,longitude,gasStation);
            transferData[0] = mMap;
            transferData[1] = url;

            Log.d("Message","Prin kanei execute ");
            getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData);
            Log.d("Message","afou kanei execute ");


            Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for Nearby Gas Stations.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Showing for Nearby Gas Stations.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
```

I want to add something inside DisplayNearbyPlaces a public variable in order to get the lats and lngs but when I use it after the getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData).get(); of GoogleUserMaps.java it gives me 0 result. I can't understand AsyncTask. Is there any way that I can wait until
getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData).get(); finishes the execute in order to get the lats and lngs ?

Thank you in advance !

my logcat 
[I want to get the result after the execute finishes as I show you in the image bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO9v8.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i wait for OnPostExecute to finish in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741510/how-can-i-wait-for-onpostexecute-to-finish-in-android)

Comment: No, I saw that I cannot understand this properly

Comment: What I can understand is that I should move all the code of private void DisplayNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) inside the onPostExecute ?

Comment: One of the answers clearly states not to use the .get() method.

Comment: The results are the same, I want to get results after the call of getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData);

Answer (score 0):

Async task runs in a seperate thread than UI thread. It would be better if you try to use a Callback interface and when onPost of Async task is called perform the action in that callback

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Yes @Strack. For this first you have to create an interface e.g PlacesListerner with methods signature of searchStarted(); searchEnded(); Then implement this interface in your activity and pass its reference via constructor in AsyncTask in your case GetNearbyPlaces  and then in preexcute method of your asyncTask call searchStarted() show some progressbar in it and in onPostExecute call ended with reference of your interface.

Comment: Sorry but I am a newbie programmer can you show me with a code example. So I need to create `private void PlaceListener(){  searchStarted(); searchEnded(); } ` ?

Answer (score 0):

@Strack I am posting code example of interface

`

```
public interface PlaceListener{
     void searchStarted();
     void searchEnded();

}



public class GetNearbyPlaces extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>
{
private String googleplaceData, url;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private PlaceListener placeListener;

public GetNearbyPlaces(PlaceListener placeListener){
    this.placeListner = placeListener;
}

//onPreExecute(){ placeListner.searchStarted();}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... objects)
{
    mMap = (GoogleMap) objects[0];
    url = (String) objects[1];

    DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
    try
    {
        googleplaceData = downloadUrl.ReadTheURL(url);
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return googleplaceData;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    placeListner.serachEnded();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
    DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
    nearbyPlacesList = dataParser.parse(s);
    DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Log.d("Message","telos execute ");

}


}
```

`

Implement the PlaceListener in Caller Activity and perform your desired task in searchEnded. You can make the parameters of your interface methods according to your desired data you want to pass

Comment: mirzaJust  just say that I have a public static list which saves the lats every time the for is running on DisplayNearbyPlaces how can I return it to GoogleUserMaps.java after the execute has done

Comment: You have to call a method of GoogleUserMaps class when your task is completed.

Comment: usermaps.doneWithListOfPoints(); and in method doneWithListOfPoints(){ // Do something} in googleMap class

Comment: I want to get a list from GetNearbyPlaces.java to GoogleUserMaps.java but it returns [] cause the it runs the case R.id.gasstation_nearby: before the execute is done

Answer (score 0):

ok. create a new call back:

```
public interface MyCallBack {
    void myTaskDone(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList);
}
```

create one in your activity:

```
MyCallBack myCallBack = new MyCallBack() {
    @Override
    public void myTaskDone(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
        DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
    }
};
```

send a reference to the Aynctask:

```
    getNearbyPlaces.execute(transferData, map, new MyCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void myTaskDone(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
            DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
        }
    });
```

complete code:

```
    public interface MyCallBack {
    void myTaskDone(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList);
}

public class GetNearbyPlaces extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {
    private String googleplaceData;
    private String url;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MyCallBack myCallBack;

    public GetNearbyPlaces(String url, GoogleMap mMap, MyCallBack myCallBack) {
        this.url = url;
        this.mMap = mMap;
        this.myCallBack = myCallBack;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        try {
            googleplaceData = downloadUrl.ReadTheURL(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return googleplaceData;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
        DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
        nearbyPlacesList = dataParser.parse(s);
        myCallBack.myTaskDone(nearbyPlacesList);
    }

}

private void DisplayNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
    /// your code
}

MyCallBack myCallBack = new MyCallBack() {
    @Override
    public void myTaskDone(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
        DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList); 
    }
};
```

How to call it:

```
    //.....
    transferData[0] = mMap;
    transferData[1] = url;

    Log.d("Message","Prin kanei execute ");
            GetNearbyPlaces getNearbyPlaces = new GetNearbyPlaces(transferData, map, myCallBack);
    getNearbyPlaces.execute();

    //or:

    GetNearbyPlaces getNearbyPlaces = new GetNearbyPlaces(transferData, map, new MyCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void myTaskDone(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
            DisplayNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
        }
    });
    getNearbyPlaces.execute();
```